# Potential multicollinearity problem between a dummy and the constant term

Tags: regression, binary-data, multicollinearity, intercept

In an OLS regression, I need to use a variable that is equal to 0 for all observations (1636) except 3 of them. I am afraid that this may generate a multicollinearity problem with the constant of the model.

My question is whether running the regression without the constant term would be advisable.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem unless you're creating training and test datasets. Random partitioning on such rare events likely would create problems in that all 3 observations could end up in one group. Depending on the underlying algorithm, convergence issues could arise, e.g., quasi- or complete separation. Do you have any information on dealing with rare event models and data mining?

Comment: Thanks @DJohnson for your answer. If I get you right, there does not seem any convergence problem when I use both the binary variable and the constant. As regards your question, I don't.

Comment: @DJohnson I realize that comments must be telegraphic.  Unfortunately that necessity seems to make yours ambiguous: does the initial "it" refer to *including* the constant term or *not including it* (which is what is asked)?  I'm pretty sure you did not mean to recommend removing the constant term on this basis, but not everyone would understand it that way.

Comment: @whuber  You are correct that I was *not* recommending removing the constant. By "it," I was referring to the issue raised by the OP as to whether sparsity would create collinearity.